# Problems to conform enum:int32 BinaryInteger

Tags: swift

I want to have an Int32 enum which I can combine logically. This is my code but Xcode syas that it doesn't conform the BinaryInteger protocol:

```
enum AppState : Int32, CaseIterable, BinaryInteger, Numeric {
    
    typealias Words = Int32.Type;
    typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int32.Type
    typealias Magnitude = Int32.Type;
    
    static func & (lhs: AppState, rhs: AppState) -> AppState {
        return (lhs.rawValue & rhs.rawValue) as! AppState;
    }

    static func | (lhs: AppState, rhs: AppState) -> AppState {
        return (lhs.rawValue | rhs.rawValue) as! AppState;
    }

    static func + (lhs: AppState, rhs: AppState) -> AppState {
        return (lhs.rawValue + rhs.rawValue) as! AppState;
    }

    static func - (lhs: AppState, rhs: AppState) -> AppState {
        return (lhs.rawValue - rhs.rawValue) as! AppState;
    }
    
       
    case APP_UNINITIALIZED = 0;
    case APP_PREFERENCES = 1;
    case APP_INSULIN_FAVORITES = 2;
    case APP_FOODS = 4;
    case APP_CONFIGURATIONS = 8;
    case APP_FULL_INITIALIZED = 16;
}

var state : AppState;

state = AppState.APP_PREFERENCES & AppState.APP_FOODS;
```

Comment: "I want to have an Int32 enum which I can combine logically" That sounds like an `OptionSet`, not `BinaryInteger`.

Comment: 4 - 1 is 3, what is 3 supposed to represent?

Comment: You cannot take 3. 1+2=3 :-)
Yes, I looked for the Optionset. But it's weird to make AppState.insert(.APP_PREFERENCES) or AppState.remove(...)
More elegant would be state = AppState.APP_PREFERENCES & AppState.APP_FOODS, isn't it? What is to do to be BinaryInteger conformed? Cannot find examples...

Comment: That was my point, there is nothing in your code preventing that calculation. Anyway, you seem to have gotten good advice in the answer below

Comment: “More elegant would be state = AppState.APP_PREFERENCES & AppState.APP_FOODS, isn't it?” Not even a little bit. That syntax is the kind of incoherent nonsense C trains you to thing is sensible. It’s not. Nobody thinks like that.

Comment: I'm totally disagree. A bitwise operation in C is absolutely logic and coherent. The problems begun, when programmers came in touch with C without to know about operators precedence for example. Mixing relational with bitwise operations make it "nonsense". Swift is a language which prever academic point of views before practical solutions.

Comment: “ A bitwise operation in C is absolutely logic and coherent. ” you’re missing my point, which is that nobody thinks like this, from the get-go. It’s something they’ve been trained to do from exposure to C. What people actually want compact storage of lots of bools which can be checked/set/cleared/intersected/unioned quickly and compactly. Bit wise operations fit the bill, but the mistake is in leaking these irrelevant implementation details into user programs. A set-like API is the natural solution that people would expect, if they weren’t tainted by these low level details

Comment: I think OptionSet is decent, because takes a step towards that (a natural, set-like API with natural API like `union()`, `intersection()`, `insert()`, etc., but I don’t think it even does a great job, because it still leaks the underlying int representation.

Comment: I think if you took a population of people who don’t know C (or C like lands like C++ and Java), they would have *absolutely no idea* what `if (currentState & AppState.APP_PREFERENCES) == AppState.APP_PREFERENCES` means. On the other hand, `if currentState.contains(AppState.preferences)` is totally natural, even obvious

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues here:

1. Code like `(lhs.rawValue | rhs.rawValue) as! AppState` will always fail, because `(lhs.rawValue | rhs.rawValue)` will always be of type `Int32`, which is not related to `AppState`. You're looking for `AppState(rawValue: lhs.rawValue | rhs.rawValue)`, which itself will always fail, because there's no value `AppState` value whose raw value is (for example) 3 (`0b01 | 0b10 == 0b11 == 3`).
2. You're trying to conform to `BinaryInteger`, but you're nowhere near close to fulfilling all of its requirements, like `bitWidth: Int`, `trailingZeroBitCount: Int`, `var words: Words`, all the relevant initializers, etc.

   Your conformance to `Numeric` is also incomplete. You need to implement `var magnitude: Self.Magnitude`, `*` and `*=`, etc. `Numeric` also refines `AdditiveArithmetic`, so you'd need unary `+`, binary `+`, unary `-` and binary `-`. `AdditiveArithmetic` also refines from `Equatable`, so you need `==`.

   None of this actually matters though, because you don't actually want to conform to BinaryInteger, it's totally off-track from what you're trying to achieve.

What you're looking for is an [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset):

```swift
struct AppState: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int32
    
    static let preferences = AppState(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let insulinFavorites = AppState(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let foods = AppState(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let configurations = AppState(rawValue: 1 << 3)

    static let uninitialized: AppState = []
    static let fullyInitialized: AppState = [.preferences, .insulinFavorites, .foods, .configurations]
}

let state: AppState = [.preferences, .foods]
```

`OptionSet` gives a Set-like API for manipulating bit fields like this, abstracting the underlying bitwise operations necessary to manipulate these values.

Some other ideas to consider:

- If space isn’t an issue (and at this scale, it probably isn’t), then a struct full of booleans might be preferable.
- If your states get more complex, and not all combinations of bits are valid, then it might be better to use an enumeration to model every single possible case (combination of bits), with a state machine that transitions between these valid states. That way, invalid states would never be possible (there wouldn’t be an enumeration to represent them)

Comment: What about  state = AppState.APP_PREFERENCES & AppState.APP_FOODS?
Is there a more elegant way for AppState.insert()/.remove() to add or remove an option?

Comment: @frameworker You *could* overload the operator, but I would highly recommend that you embrace the Swift style.